# Combinatorics question about picking exactly a objects out of b objects given n picks

Tags: combinatorics

My combinatorics are very rusty and I hope you guys can help me with this kind of question. Lets say there is a bag with 50 balls in it. There are 5 black balls and 45 white balls. How to calculate the probability of picking **exactly** 2 black balls given 4 picks.
How would this differ if we would need to get **at least** 2 black balls out of 4 picks?

EDIT : all 4 balls are picked at once

Comment: Here's a template to follow:  suppose you want the probability of choosing exactly one black ball out of four picks.  There are $\binom {50}4$ ways to choose with no restriction.  There are $\binom 51$ ways to choose one black ball, and $\binom {45}3$ ways to choose three white balls, so the answer is $\binom {5}1\times \binom {45}3\big /\binom {50}4$.

Comment: Do you replace each ball after every pick? Or do you pick all four at once?

Comment: Thanks you very much man. I think i start to see how it works. But why is only (45,3)/(50,4) not ((5,1) * (45,3)) / (50,4). And yes Im picking all 4 balls at once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\frac{{5\choose 2}\cdot {45\choose 2}}{50\choose 4}$ for part $1$.

For part $2$, there are $\frac{{5\choose 2}\cdot{45\choose 2}+{5\choose 3}\cdot{45\choose1}+{5\choose 4}}{50\choose 4}$.

Comment: Ty very much man, whats most important I think I actually understand how this is done now, much appreciated :)